# 'xoff' not working when using python script to run 'xoff' on linux. Any suggestions?

Tags: python, linux, pexpect

I am accessing a linux server (telnet) and then running commands on it using python.

I am meant to automate some processes using python including one in which many errors appear and I must type `xoff` to stop the errors from appearing so I can continue entering more commands.

This works when I do it manually, although when I do it through python, the command just doesn't work. I use pexpect module and use this code: `child.sendline("xoff")`. Don't worry, `child` is defined already.

Next I type `child.expect(".*")` and then print(child.after) which prints the output, which still is the errors that were meant to have stopped by using `xoff`.

Any suggestions on how to fix this?

BTW I am using Python 2.7.8

For ANY questions you ask, or any more information you need feel free to ask me and I will reply as quick as possible.

Thanks in advance.